# Trying to add day by day when adding new row in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCqh9.jpg)      VS      [I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MWNp.jpg)

> I want to do is every click of + button it will add row and the date field will have a value that is adding 1 day per row... Im only a begginer in vue js

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"  @click="addRow">+</button></th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.id">
        <td><input type="date" style="width:170px;" class="form-control" v-bind:value="row.date = 
        AddingDate(row.date)"> </input></td
        <td><input type="time" class="form-control" v-model="row.time_in"> </input></td>
        <td><input type="time" class="form-control" v-model="row.time_out"></input></td>
        <td><button type="button" @click="removeElement(index);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my methods, not adding day by day it add but only at the first click I don't know why

```
export default {
      data(){
        return{
          rows:[],    

        }
      },computed:{
        add1(){
          return this.rows.map((row)=>{
          var date = new Date(row.date)
        let newdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
        return  new Date(newdate).toISOString().slice(0,10)
          })

        }

      },methods:{   

    addRow() {         
         this.rows.push({
          time_in:"07:00",
          time_out:"16:00",
          paid:'2020-09-17',
        })
    
      }

        }
       

    }
```

Comment: your code works as expected - though the intermediate `newdate` is superfluous (`date.toISOString().slice(0,10)` works just as well)

Comment: so what could I do?

Comment: Oh, I don't know, as I said, the code you posted will add a day - if you get "more than a month" then perhaps put some debugging console.log's in the code to see what the function is being called with and what it returns

Comment: I got an error "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function."

Comment: oh, you haven't posted enough code to see why you get that error

Comment: but that is the code I wrote related to that logic

Comment: but the code that is an infinite loop is code you also wrote, but have not shared - we can't see it, we can't debug it for you, we can't tell you what *you did wrong™*

Comment: The variable here is wrong. from what I see. You should use the correct logic. You should set a variable for global which set the last day. And then you just add one day per click

Comment: yes something like that it will add 1 day per click but i dont know how to do it can u pls provide the code?

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @JaromandaX pls check my code I edit it..  it will add 1day but in the first click only of button "+" not adding 1 day every click of the button

Comment: You need to explain the situation better. What is your target and what is current situation.

Comment: I will put a picture on it

Comment: pls check the picture

Comment: My guess was right. The problem is the addRow()

Comment: @Ahfa Do you have Idea to solve this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024707/how-to-display-data-in-table-td-depends-on-the-value-of-table-th-in-laravel-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read is, the wrong here is the logic

```
addRow() {
        
        this.rows.push({
          time_in:"07:00",
          time_out:"16:00",
          date:'2020-09-17',
        })
    
      }; ==> this just push a row

   AddingDate(value){
        var date = new Date(value)
        let newdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
        return  new Date(newdate).toISOString().slice(0,10)

        } ==> this add one day every row you provide
```

I believe what you want is to create a day

```
export default {
      data(){
        return{
          lastDate: new Date(), <== here to set lastDate
          rows:[],    

        }
      },methods:{   

    addRow() {
if(this.rows.length){
         let row = this.rows[this.rows.length -1];
         let date = new Date(row.date)
         let newdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
         this.lastDate = new Date(newdate).toISOString().slice(0,10)
} else {
   this.lastDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
}
         let newdata = {
          time_in:"07:00",
          time_out:"16:00",
          paid: this.lastDate,
        })
        this.rows.push(newdata);
      }

        }
       

    }
```

use the value normally like the other input

Comment: not working :( pls also check I edit my code I try to put it on computed.. It works but It add 1 day at the first click of button '+'

Comment: just make validation, if it's first index, dont add

Comment: I mean it will add only 1 day in the first index not adding in the next indexes

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Now it's a different thing, is the Date is paid?  it was date variable, now it's paid variable

Comment: ' this.lastDate = new Date(newdate).toISOString().slice(0,10)' from this line where did u get `newdate` ?

Comment: let newdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

Comment: let newdata = {
          time_in:"07:00",
          time_out:"16:00",
          paid: this.lastDate,
        })
        this.rows.push(newdata);

Comment: I've updated the code to the latest. it should work or you can use Kamlesh style

Answer (score 0):

try this i tested it.

use `Date` object so you can manipulate date and add to new row

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="addRow">+</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.id">
            <td>
                <input type="date" style="width:170px;" class="form-control" v-model="row.date" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" v-model="row.time_in" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" v-model="row.time_out" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" @click="removeElement(index);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in javascript

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [
                {
                    time_in: "07:00",
                    time_out: "16:00",
                    date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
                },
            ],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addRow() {
            let index = this.rows.length - 1;
            let lastDate = this.rows[index];
            let oldDate = new Date(lastDate.date);
            oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 1);
            this.rows.push({
                time_in: "07:00",
                time_out: "16:00",
                date: oldDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10),
            });
        },
    },
};
```